# SQL select works on laptop but not when published

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am while I am testing on my latop, using the same `SQL server` as the live site, this insert query works fine, but when I publish it to my server, I get an error on

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Here is the code

```
Dim bResults As New Boolean
Dim cInsertCommand As SqlCommand
Dim m_SqlConn As New SqlConnection
Dim SqlAdp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()

m_SqlConn = CrmConnectionSting()
If m_SqlConn.State <> Data.ConnectionState.Open Then m_SqlConn.Open()

If dParameters.Count <> 0 Then
    cInsertCommand = New SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Activity] ([actDate], [actTime], [actDuration], [actCategoryId], [actCustomerName], [actUser], [actCreatedBy], [actCreatedDate]) VALUES (Convert(DateTime,'18-03-2016 00:00:00',103), Convert(DateTime,'10:00:00', 14), 60, 1, 'test1', 'user1', 'admin', Convert(DateTime,'18/03/2016 13:05:06',103))", m_SqlConn)

    SqlAdp.InsertCommand = cInsertCommand
    SqlAdp.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
End if
```

Why would this be, like I said it is the same Db, the date and time format on all servers are the same.

All other select queries work fine.

My laptop in `Win10`, server `Win2008 IIS 7`.

Comment: I would guess the locality settings differ. Anyway, you're using datestyle 103 both for dd-MM-yyyy and dd/MM/yyyy styles. Datestyle 103 is dd/MM/yyyy, 105 is dd-MM-yyyy.

Comment: Also, why are you using `datetime` datatype for `actTime`? Looks like you're only interested in the time, but it gets filled with `01-01-1900 10:00:00.000`.

Comment: Hi HoneyBadger, any relation to Nick Cummins?  I tried 105 with no change in the results.  And yes actTime is a DateTime format, It was date and I was getting an error on SELECT.  The Regional settings on the IIS and SQL server are the same as my Laptop.  Thank you